# Reassigning a nested key value

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary

I'm trying to reassign a nested value after the user selects the row which the object is on.  Im basically remaking a read receipt feature.  It keeps throwing an error saying "Expression is not assignable" when i use this:

```
[[self.conversations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKeyPath:@"recipientRead"] = true;
```

and it says "Property 'recipientRead' not found on object of type 'id'" when i use this:

```
    self.conversations[indexPath.row].recipientRead = true;
```

How do I access this object for this index row for this key and assign it a new variable?

This is what my conversations object looks like:

```
conversations = (
"<Convo: 0x174117970, objectId: kq1H963zwX, localId: (null)> {\n    leanId = 7FvjCFbVcv;\n    messageBody = Test;\n    recipientDisplayName = Ian;\n    recipientId = SXeTdhJcRn;\n    recipientRead = 0;\n    senderDisplayName = user2;\n    senderId = rBi8XjVxx5;\n    senderRead = 1;\n    timeStamp = \"2015-08-18 14:31:48\";\n}",
"<Convo: 0x17410e340, objectId: 4VAkXEJK4i, localId: (null)> {\n    leanId = maLdMRcsRS;\n    messageBody = \"Test 555\";\n    recipientDisplayName = Ian;\n    recipientId = SXeTdhJcRn;\n    senderDisplayName = user2;\n    senderId = rBi8XjVxx5;\n    timeStamp = \"2015-08-16 15:38:19\";\n}",
"<Convo: 0x17010f9c0, objectId: Sbct8LnaMg, localId: (null)> {\n    leanId = tOYG4Einld;\n    messageBody = Test;\n    recipientDisplayName = Ian;\n    recipientId = SXeTdhJcRn;\n    senderDisplayName = user2;\n    senderId = rBi8XjVxx5;\n    timeStamp = \"2015-08-16 15:32:45\";\n}",
```

Comment: Hard to know, since you don't say what kind of thing is fetched by `valueForKeyPath:@"recipientRead"`. Do you mean `setValue:forKeyPath:`?

Comment: Wow duh. thanks matt.  Is there a way to type cast this to an int because its now throwing "Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'id' is disallowed with ARC"?

Comment: First of all, there is no such thing as `true`. You should be using `YES`. Second, `YES` is not an object. You have to use `@YES`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because .dot notation requires strong typing

```
ClassName *conversation = self.conversations[indexPath.row];
conversation.recipientRead = YES;
```

Simply use your own classname since it's not specified in your example ;)